# HttpPostedFileBase to Resized Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-resizing, httppostedfilebase

I have the following line of code which takes my `HttpPostedFileBase` and converts it to an image.

I have messed around with Encoder Parameteres to try and resize the image but can't seem to do this.

What is the best way to resize the image to 250x250?

I would also prefer it to take the middle of the image as 250x250 rectangle rather than somewhere random.

What is the most space efficent way to convert and save the image as it will be going in the database?

Please note that `model.Image` is of type `HttpPostedFileBase`.

```
var image = Image.FromStream(model.Image.InputStream, true, true);

ImageCodecInfo jpgInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    .Where(codecInfo => codecInfo.MimeType == "image/jpeg").First();
using (EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
{
    encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)50);

    //quality should be in the range [0..100]
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        image64 = base64String;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to resize it or crop it? 'Take the middle of the image' is confusing

Comment: Any whatever is easiest. As this is a prototype

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an established library like [ImageResizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/); that way, you avoid re-inventing the wheel. If you are concerned about space efficiency (file size), use the JPEG format with maximum compression. Note that using JPEG's lossy encoding will drastically reduce image quality. If you want to use a lossless encoding, try PNG. Compressing PNG images is quite difficult in .NET, in my experience. I searched in vain awhile back for a single library that would do it and all I found were thick-client Windows applications.

Comment: http://nquant.codeplex.com is good for png compression, I've literally just finished an image serving solution that uses this.

Comment: "I set out to create this quantizer and the results are images 3x smaller than their 32 bit originals with practically no perceptible quality loss." Unfortunately, it seems as though his algorithm is lossy. My search awhile back was for a lossless compressor. Thanks for the link, though; this could be useful!